# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Uri' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using HTML Agility to get all the images since image dont always have absolute path i am trying to do following. But line marked below in the code generates error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Uri' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I am not sure how to fix this i tried so many option but keep on getting one or the other error

```
List<String> imgList = (from x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                      where x.Attributes["src"] != null
                      select x.Attributes["src"].Value.ToLower()).ToList<String>();

List<String> AbsoluteImageUrl = new List<String>();

foreach (String element in imgList)
{
    AbsoluteImageUrl = new Uri(baseUrl, element); //GIVES ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler generates an error, because the type of `AbsoluteImageUrl` is not compatible with the type of your `Uri`. If you need to add the `Uri` to a string list, you should obtain its underlying string (e.g. `Uri.AbsolutePath`). In this case, the code would look like this:

```
AbsoluteImageUrl.Add(new Uri(baseUrl, element).AbsolutePath);
```

On the other hand, if you need an `Uri` list instead, keep your original code and change the type of `AbsoluteImageUrl`:

```
List<Uri> AbsoluteImageUrl = new List<Uri>();
```

Once this is done, you should use `AbsoluteImageUrl.Add` in the loop to add the `Uri` to the list.

---

Regarding the discussion in comments about difference between `Uri.ToString()` and `Uri.AbsolutePath`, they have a different definitions per the official MSDN, so it depends on the OP's requirements which he/she should use. The source code of `Uri.ToString`, on a side note, is as follows, so it is fundamentally different from `AbsolutePath`:

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.Infrastructure)]
public override string ToString()
{
    if (this.m_Syntax == null)
    {
        if (this.m_iriParsing && this.InFact(Flags.HasUnicode))
        {
            return this.m_String;
        }
        return this.OriginalString;
    }
    this.EnsureUriInfo();
    if (this.m_Info.String == null)
    {
        if (this.Syntax.IsSimple)
        {
            this.m_Info.String = this.GetComponentsHelper(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, (UriFormat) 0x7fff);
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_Info.String = this.GetParts(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
        }
    }
    return this.m_Info.String;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
AbsoluteImageUrl.Add(new Uri(baseUrl, element).ToString());
```

Comment: Well, make sure it does what you want first :)

Comment: It depends on the OP's requirements whether `ToString()` or `AbsolutePath` is more suitable (for the AbsolutePath based solution, see my answer).

Comment: Hmm, [good point](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/04/uriabsoluteuri-and-uritostring-are-not.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Uri> AbsoluteImageUrl = new List<Uri>();

foreach (String element in imgList)
{
    AbsoluteImageUrl.Add(new Uri(baseUrl, element));
}
```